# How do I track keywords entered in Google Search using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: search, google-tag-manager, keyword

I want to know what keywords brings users to our website. The result should be such that, every time a user clicks on a link of the company's website, the page URL, timestamp and keywords entered in search are recorded.

I'm not really much of a coder, but I do understand the basics of Google Tag Manager. So I'd appreciate some solutions that can allow me to implement this in GTM's interface itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't track them. Well, that is unless you can deploy your GTM on Google's search result pages. Which you're extremely unlikely to be able to do.

HTTPS prevents query parameters to get populated for referrers, which is what the core reason for it is.

You still can, technically, track Google search keywords for the extremely rare users who manage to use Google via http, but again, no need to do anything in GTM. GA will automatically track it with its legacy keyword tracking.

Finally, you can use Google Search Console where Google reports what keywords were used to get to your site. That information, however, is so heavily sampled that it's just not joinable to any of the GA data. It is possible, however, to join GSC with GA, but that will only lead to GA having a separate report from GSC and that's it. No real data joins.